# Is there a limit to how many backup files I can restore from for a single database on RDS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

[The AWS documentation for using native restore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) specifies that restoring from multiple files is allowed:

> To avoid errors while restoring multiple files, make sure that all the
>   backup files have the same prefix, and that no other files use that
>   prefix.
>
> The following example shows multiple-file restore.
>
> exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name='database_name',
>   @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/bakup_file_*'

How many files can I restore from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit of 10 backup files.

When attempting to restore from more than 10 backup files, the following error occurs:

> The Restore task is unable to restore from more than 10 backup
>   file(s). Please reduce the number of files matched and try again.

Comment: Amazon has updated the documentation to include this limitation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore